# Flex 4.5 DateTimeFormatter: why is timeZone specific information ignored in dateTimePattern?

Tags: apache-flex, datetime, flex4.5, formatter

```
var df:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter();
df.dateTimePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z";
var formattedDate:String = df.format(new Date(2011, 6, 7));
```

formattedDate value is "2011/07/07 00:00:00 ". what am i doing wrong? cannot format nothing timeZone specific? i'm getting crazy about this... help is appreciated a lot

Answer (score 2):

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html#setDateTimePattern%28%29 .

The documentation says that some operating systems don't support the timezone pattern... Apparently because the class implementing the formatting uses OS specific functions for timezone.

Workaround would be to implement your own formatter.

Comment: Yeah, windows isn't good for locale specific timezones (for some oddball reason).  Your best bet would be to extend the formatter and add the timezone manually based on `Date.timezoneOffset`

Comment: thank you. i thought about that, but i just couldn't understand why default method with dateTimePattern doesn't work. and i still don't. the standart Date.toString method outputs timezone info, the timezoneOffset property does that to, how can it be that operating system doesn't support the pattern of Z. strange...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to write your own formatter...

In Flex 4.5 they added some new localization features.  You can't unfortunately always depend on the system to correctly identify the locale automatically.

Here adobe describes four different methods you can employ of identifying the locale of the user and setting it.  Once this is set, the formatter will work correctly so you won't need to roll your own formatter.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c-1c03f02c12bd00c4763-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-99797f112bd080033f-8000

Comment: thank you for suggestion. i gues i will write my own formatter buy extending DateTimeFormatter and adding that Z info manualy